# How to find a string in a list of tuples by defining a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

This may be simple, but I would like to check for an existing string(s)inside of a list of tuples, and then return the corresponding tuple(s) that the string appears in. I also want it to be a case insensitive search so that it can pick up letters regardless of capitalization, etc.
I would like to define a function that will do this, this is what I have tried:

```
test_scores = [('Math midterm, 87','math final, 92'),
('english essay, 100','english midterm, 87','english final, 99'),
('science midterm, 95','science final, 100')]

def searchScores(searchString):
    for i in range (len(test_scores)):
        for j in range (len(test_scores[i])):
            if test_scores[i][j].casefold() == searchString.casefold():
                print (test_scores[i])
```

I want to be able to input my search like so:

```
searchScores('math')
searchScores('87')
```

which should return:

```
('Math midterm, 87','math final, 92')
('english essay, 100','english midterm, 87','english final, 99')
```

However this returned nothing when I inputted a string to check...

Let me know if any clarification is needed. Thanks!

Comment: what is test_scores ? Also please provide expected result.

Comment: Your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't show any output for u but assuming the `test_scores` variables to be a "list of tuples" which has strings, this worked for me.

```py
test_scores = [("abc","def"),("ghi","jkl"),("mno","pqr")]

def searchScores(searchString):
    for tup in test_scores:
        for ele in tup:
            if ele.lower() == searchString.lower():
                print(tup)

st = input("Enter : ")

searchScores(st)
```

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am fairly new to Python. But I believe the issue I am having is because I am searching for singular words... a few of my tuples are like ('Ms. Sally Jones', '23 years old') .... and if I am searching for only 'Sally' it returns nothing because it is not formatted ===> ('Ms','Sally','Jones') if that makes any sense at all

Comment: @Emma how do u mean singular words?

Comment: didn't mean to press enter on that yet.. my bad!

Comment: oh! for that u can always use membership operator `in`. it works like `"hel" in "hello"` results `True`. so `"sally".lower() in "Ms. Sally Jones".lower()` will always return `True`

Comment: I updated the post, realized that example was not very informative! But would using the `in` function return the tuple? Or just True/False?

Comment: @Emma u can replace `if test_scores[i][j].casefold() == searchString.casefold():` to `if  searchString.casefold() in test_scores[i][j].casefold()` and leave the if block as it is. the only difference it would make is that `==` checks if both the strings are exactly the same and 'in' operator checks if the given string is a substring of the other (the given string is a part of the other one). so `"Maths midterm" == "Maths"` is False, but `"Maths" in "Maths midterm"` is True. so in ur case, if you pass "87" as function argument, every single tuple containing it would be printed.

Comment: Works!! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The function in this code will search each tuple for the search string.

```
test_scores =[('math', '87'), ('english', '33'), ('67', 'math')]

def search_scores(scores, searchString):
  lower_scores = [(score[0].lower(), score[1].lower()) for score in scores]
  items = list(filter(lambda x:searchString.lower() in x, lower_scores))

  return items

print(search_scores(test_scores, 'math'))
```

Comment: Sorry.. I just updated the post. The issue I am having is finding just `'math'` inside of `'Math midterm, 87'` , for example